# Git: Bulk change of commit dates

Tags: git, git-rewrite-history

When I need to change the commit dates of various commits, I use an interactive rebase and change them one by one.

How could I change them all in a single command ? In other words, I need to apply a given command to all commits that would be listed in an interactive rebase.

Thanks

Comment: how should the date be changed? All set to the same time, or all moved one hour later, etc?

Answer (score 6):

## Filter-Repo

`git filter-branch` is deprecated. Instead, use `git filter-repo`. You will need to install it.

Here is an [excellent article](https://blog.kawzeg.com/2019/12/19/git-filter-repo.html) about how to use git-filter-repo to modify the commit date. The [git-filter-repo documentation](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/master/Documentation/git-filter-repo.txt) explains the concept of `--commit-callback` pretty well.

## A very simple example

Let's reset the timezone of all commit dates to zero.

```py
# Save this as ../change_time.py
def handle(commit):
    "Reset the timezone of all commits."
    date_str = commit.author_date.decode('utf-8')
    [seconds, timezone] = date_str.split()
    new_date = f"{seconds} +0000"
    commit.author_date = new_date.encode('utf-8')

handle(commit)
```

```sh
# You need to be in a freshly-cleaned repo. Or use --force.
git clone <...> your_repo
cd your_repo
# First just a dry run.
git filter-repo --dry-run --commit-callback "$(cat ../change_time.py)"
# And now do it for real
git filter-repo --commit-callback "$(cat ../change_time.py)"
```

Comment: https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#_warning is a reference for the "git filter-branch is deprecated" comment.

Answer (score 2):

`git rebase` supports [the `--exec` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---execltcmdgt), which will do exactly that.

> `-x <cmd>`
>
> `--exec <cmd>`
>
> Append "exec <cmd>" after each line creating a commit in the final history. <cmd> will be interpreted as one or more shell commands. Any command that fails will interrupt the rebase, with exit code 1.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it for the current date:

```bash
git rebase main --exec 'git commit --amend --date="now" --no-edit --allow-empty'
```

Answer (score -1):

## Filter-Repo

In other answer it was suggested to save code to file .py and run it with
`git filter-repo --commit-callback "$(cat ../<your file name>.py)"` but then it ignored in my case all whitespaces which in python breaks syntax. For me worked pasting it directly into command. I am using Windows, tested on PowerShell, beginner in these things.

### More advanced example

Set new date for commits based on commits containing given string. But **BEWARE**, you shouldn't change date unless you have really good reason!

```py
if(b'[structural-programming]' in commit.message):
    base_date = datetime(2021,1,1,0,0,0)
    print(commit.message,' new date: ',base_date)
    commit.committer_date = f'{int(datetime.timestamp(base_date))} +0100'.encode('utf-8')
    commit.author_date = f'{int(datetime.timestamp(base_date))} +0100'.encode('utf-8')
elif(b'[intro-into-programming]' in commit.message):
    base_date = datetime(2021,1,2,0,0,0)
    print(commit.message,' new date: ',base_date)
    commit.committer_date = f'{int(datetime.timestamp(base_date))} +0100'.encode('utf-8')
    commit.author_date = f'{int(datetime.timestamp(base_date))} +0100'.encode('utf-8')
else:
    base_date = datetime(2021,1,3,0,0,0)
    print(commit.message,' new date: ',base_date)
    commit.committer_date = f'{int(datetime.timestamp(base_date))} +0100'.encode('utf-8')
    commit.author_date = f'{int(datetime.timestamp(base_date))} +0100'.encode('utf-8')
```

and how it is used in console:

```
git filter-repo --commit-callback "                            
 [seconds, timezone] = commit.committer_date.decode('utf-8').split()
 
 if(b'[structural-programming]' in commit.message):
     base_date = datetime(2021,1,1,0,0,0)
     print(commit.message,' new date: ',base_date)
     commit.committer_date = f'{int(datetime.timestamp(base_date))} +0100'.encode('utf-8')
     commit.author_date = f'{int(datetime.timestamp(base_date))} +0100'.encode('utf-8')
 elif(b'[intro-into-programming]' in commit.message):
     base_date = datetime(2021,1,2,0,0,0)
     print(commit.message,' new date: ',base_date)
     commit.committer_date = f'{int(datetime.timestamp(base_date))} +0100'.encode('utf-8')
     commit.author_date = f'{int(datetime.timestamp(base_date))} +0100'.encode('utf-8')
 else:
     base_date = datetime(2021,1,3,0,0,0)
     print(commit.message,' new date: ',base_date)
     commit.committer_date = f'{int(datetime.timestamp(base_date))} +0100'.encode('utf-8')
     commit.author_date = f'{int(datetime.timestamp(base_date))} +0100'.encode('utf-8')
 "
```