# Complete account deletion on Github- commits made my same ssh key ported into new account

Tags: github, ssh

[image]

I deleted my old github account earlier this year, so that my old content is labeled as 'Ghost'.  However, when i used my old ssh-keys to push into my new github account, Github went back in time and linked my new account to all my old commits using that key.  Is there a way to get github to deflag these commits and label them too as Ghost?

not sure where else to ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commit-user association is set after the account email.
If your new account uses the same email as the old deleted one, chances are GitHub would show those commits with your current account avatar.

Using the old ssh key should not work to push, unless you set your old *public* SSH key in your new GitHub account profile.
Or if you are actually using an HTTPS URL, in which case no SSH key (old or new) would be used anyway.

To "deflag these commits and label them too as Ghost", you would need to amend those commits, changing their author *email*.
Or you need to make sure your new account is not using your old commit author email.

Comment: I see, I used a separate email to dump all the github notifications, which was the same between accounts, I also just put my old ssh key in my new account.  There are probably 3-4 years of full time dev work, I'm not sure how to begin amending these commits

Comment: @Taylor `git filter-repo` (as [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74315442/6309)), with mailmap (as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70574113/6309)), using a date range (as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60873857/6309)).