# Change date of commits on github

Tags: git, github

I want to change date of 4 commits that I pushed to github today, say pushing them back by 3 dates.

I have 2 problems, and it seems that they are relevant:

1. I use git rebase to fix the date of commits, but when I pushed them to github, the final commit will be labled today. [image]

2. The public github page will still show the change I made as today.

Is there anyway I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a `git rebase -i --committer-date-is-author-date --ignore-date` (with [Git 2.29+, Q4 2020](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63751470/6309)) when [changing your date](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58622282/6309).

If not, the committer date would be today (IE, by default, the date when the rebase was done).

Or you can also use [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo), as in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60873857/6309), except the code would need (as in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/JuniorJPDJ/77c8a6bad05e6e0205c5edee03ce978c))

```
commit.author_date = commit.committer_date = new_date.encode('utf-8')
```

Meaning filter-repo needs, in its callback, to change the author *and committer* date.